# magento-paypal payflow-pro- test credit/debit card works with live mode

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, paypal-payments-pro

I have configured Paypal Payflow Pro and live mode is set but when i use test card details for any card type then it accept it and successfully checkout with the same.
When i have set Payment Action -Authorization in admin payment settings then it works fine but not working when Payment action will be Sale.

what is exact issue , i am not able to trace it !

Comment: If you didt found solution still, better to contact paypal.

Comment: I have already opened ticket there and waiting for their response.

Comment: they will reply for sure, but they will take more time initially.

Answer (score 5):

I have got response from paypal support team and they had an issue whereby some of the processed transaction is not appearing in their PayPal account.
their developers fixed it and it's working properly now.
I am posting answer so it may help someone in future.